Why do string enums and heterogeneous enums throw an error when assigning a member literal string type to them?
TypeScript 5.0 introduced an overhaul of enums as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#50528. From these descriptions, the type of an enum is actually a union type of the literal types of its members. However, the type checking strategy for string enums and heterogeneous enums do not conform to the above rules. See the code below(typescript version: 5.6.2).
enum B { // string enum
  B1 = '1',
  B2 = '2',
}
enum C { // heterogeneous enum
  C1 = 1,
  C2 = 2,
  C3 = '1',
  C4 = '2',
}
const b1: B = '1'; // ts error: Type '"1"' cannot be assigned to type 'B'
const c12: C = '1'; // ts error: Type '"1"' cannot be assigned to type 'C'

Why is the type check result of enum different from the type check result of real union type? Is this a bug of enum or is there something wrong with my understanding of the new features of enum above?

How is this different from your previous question "How heterogeneous enumerations perform type checking?"?

This behavior isn't affected by the overhaul. "Union enums" are unions of the types of their members which are literal types. But the fact that the members are assignable to literal types does not mean that literal types are assignable to the members. String enums are treated as nominal subtypes of their corresponding string literal types. So B.B1 is assignable to "1" but not vice versa. That forces people to use the enum object to get enum values, which is part of the point of enums (or, in my opinion, a good reason to avoid enums and just use literals). See linked q/a for more info

This defeats the purpose of using enums. What would happen in the future if the team decides that "1" is not descriptive enough and want to use "one" instead?
It is best practice to always parse the value to an enum and then handling any issues you encounter inside parsing it. (if the input comes from the outside)
